# Generic import of oracle tables with sqoop

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop, sqoop

We have many tables in oracle that we want to move to hdfs for archival purposes. We are looking for a generic way to copy the tables to hadoop. The columns of the tables are mostly of type NUMBER, VARCHAR2 and DATE.

We know sqoop is the tool to do the job most efficiently. The output format should be AVRO, because of its schema evolution capabilities.
When we took a closer look we found out that handling date and timestamp columns with the data connector for oracle and hadoop is problematic. Basically the two options are setting `timestamp.string=false` and store DATE columns as `long`. The downside is that you lose timezone information. Also if we want to export the data back to oracle DATE columns have to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`
The other option is to set `timestamp.string=true`. The problem we have with this option is that, the generated AVRO schema for a DATE column is still `{null,long}` why an error is thrown when a record is written to the AVRO file. As a workaround we can set the `--map-column-java DATE_COL=String` parameter for every DATE column. But since we are looking for a gerneric solution, this is not a very good option.

Do you have any suggestions on how you solved this problem?

Comment: What about exporting in two columns with the long option. The first would be the long and the second the time zone? And you can export back properly to Oracle.

Comment: This would also require, that we specify each DATE column for each table. We are looking for a more generic solution, where the only thing you specify is the tablename, which is then set into a predefined sqoop import command.